# Hair not moving when you move it's bone

Tags: rigging

I parented a polygon hair made with bezier curves to my character's head, but, when I move the bone connected to the head, the hair doesn't move with it, what do I do?

Comment: Can you please share settings of your modifiers?

Answer (score 2):

I'm supposing that you parented your hair object to the head object and parented the head to an armature which include a "head" bone, weighted (automatically or manually) to the head vertices of your mesh.

When you move a bone you are moving the vertices of the mesh without affecting the origin of the object. If your hair is another object parented to the object called "head" it will not move as the Head origin is not moving.
To get the right movement you must select all of your hair objects, then Shift Select the Head Bone, then press Ctrl P and choose  "Bone" option.
In this way the bone movement will affect the head vertices and the hair origins in the same way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I hardly remember why I asked this question all that time ago, and I didn't even remember this until you answered. Thank you, but I have moved on to other works.